# Ruby on Rails - JavaScript ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 4.2.6 and Ruby 2.2.4p230.

I am doing Ruby on Rails 4 Essential Traning tutorial, so I am new to Ruby on Rails.

I have a problem with a simple JavaScript function defined in /assets/javascripts folder.
When loading the page that is supposed to call the function, it does nothing. It should show an alert.
I checked the JavaScript console and showed ReferenceError: jsRoar is not defined.

I have a manifest file called public.js in /assets/javascripts and I require demo.js file in it:

```
//= require demo
```

and demo.js file in /assets/javascripts with jsRoar function defined:

```
function jsRoar(name) {
  alert('I am ' + name + '. Hear me roar!');
}
```

Then I include the manifest file with a helper in /views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag('public') %>
```

And lastly I'm trying to run it in /views/demo/index.html.erb file using

```
<%= link_to('Roar', '#', :onclick => "jsRoar('JavaScript'); return true;") %>
```

and

```
<%= javascript_tag("jsRoar('Rails');") %>
```

I tried using JavaScript directly like

```
 <%= javascript_tag("alert('blah blah blah')") %>
```

and it worked.

Why is JavaScript console saying that jsRoar is not defined? Could it be a problem with my Rails version? The tutorial uses Rails 4.0.0.

@EDIT My Gosh, sorry, I wrote that I use Rails 2.4.6 instead of 4.2.6

More info:

In the console I get:

```
Started GET "/assets/demo.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95‌​c05.js?body=1" for ::1 at 20 16-04-02 20:00:50 +0200)
Started GET "/assets/public.self-1d8e221ce33ae6895c0dc108af782be06d67eee7ddcbbe39856d455f5c5‌​c4ce1.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2016-04-02 20:00:50 +0200
```

When I check the source of the demo.self-(...).js in my browser in the development mode there is:

```
(function() {


}).call(this);
```

And in public.self-(...).js I have:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files 
// listed below. 
// (...)
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
```

And there's no //= require demo

@EDIT 2

Okay, I set up a new app and put all of these files there and I got an error:

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled in Demo#index 

 Showing c:/(...)/testing/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production.
Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( public.js )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server
```

I think I got this error in the original app too.
When I add the declaration of the asset, the JavaScript functions don't work just like in the previous app.

@EDIT 3

I have returned to Rails again and I still have this problem in **Rails 5**. I have found out another thing that stuff that is in demo.coffee is being turned to JavaScript and does work on the website (once and only when the site loads but I think it's turbolinks problem that I'm going to find out later). I guess something's wrong with the demo.js file. It's like the code from there isn't processed into the server. I did check the network console and the demo.self is loaded there, but as I said the file still has only this

```
(function() {


}).call(this);
```

What the heck am I doing wrong? I have followed the tutorial pretty carefully this time.

Comment: Just tried using the same setup as you locally and everything worked fine. Have you checked the source of demo.js in development mode?

Comment: Check the browser console network, whether  the java script file having the function is loaded or not ?